# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Facebook\WebDriver\ChromeOptions' not found

Tags: php, selenium, php-webdriver

```
namespace Facebook\WebDriver;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';

$options = new ChromeOptions();
```

I have read this [link](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/ChromeOptions) when i creating object of class `ChromeOptions` getting error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Facebook\WebDriver\ChromeOptions' not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$options = new Chrome\ChromeOptions();
```

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
```

to the top.