# Uncaught exception when passing exception up through class

Tags: php, class, oop, exception

I have a class named **User** that calls one of its own methods, **setUsername()**, upon construction, within a try/catch block. If **setUsername()** fails, it will throw an exception:

```
class User {
    private $username;

    public function __construct($input_username) {
        try {
            $this->setUsername($input_username);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    private function setUsername($username) {
      if(1 != 0)
         throw new Exception("1 does not equal 0!!!");
      $this->username = $username;
    }

}
```

I then create a new **User** in an external function, in a separate file, within its own try/catch block. It's supposed to catch the exception passed through from the **User** class constructor:

```
namespace UserController;

function createUser(){
    try {
        $user = new \User('sample-user');
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Why, then, am I still getting an "Uncaught Exception" error?

Comment: Try replacing all instances of `Exception` with `\Exception`. My guess is the code that instantiates the user is in a namespace, which means `Exception` refers to a non-existing class within that namespace.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `echo $e->getMessage();`?

Comment: @Jeto -- You're correct. The code instantiating the user is in a namespace. I just added that to my question. However, it doesn't seem to have rectified the issue

Comment: You forgot a ";" after `throw new Exception("1 does not equal 0!!!")`

Comment: @Felippe Duarte -- Yes, there should be a semicolon there. Whoops.

Comment: @Barmar -- Yes, it should. I've fixed that as well. It doesn't solve this issue, but is a bug. Thanks.

Comment: @fswebb There is no way a code wrapped in `try` => `catch (\Exception $e)` would generate an `Uncaught Exception` error, since this is the base class of all exceptions. Are you sure you replaced it there?

Comment: @Jeto -- I'm sure. I ended up having to add an `use \Exception;` statement right under the namespace declaration. I truly, truly appreciate your help here.

Comment: @fswebb That's really weird, and doesn't sound right. But glad you solved it I guess :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Facebook\WebDriver\ChromeOptions' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767408/php-fatal-error-uncaught-error-class-facebook-webdriver-chromeoptions-not-fo)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was missing a statement at the top of the file that instantiates the class, since it is namespaced. After the namespace declaration, it needs to say:

```
use \Exception;
```